# Connecting two Flash Media Servers via a NetConnection, but not able to use the call method

Tags: flash-media-server

I'm wondering if anyone has had any luck connecting one FMS to another FMS (two different physical machines) via a server-side NetConnection, then having the first call a method on the second.

I'm able to make the connection fine (though the NetConnection.Connect.Success event never fires).  After which I have the Flash client calling a method on the first server, which then calls a method on the second server, both via nc.call of course.

The nc.call from the first FMS to the second doesn't get received by the second FMS. No error, nothing in the logs, just ignored it seems.

I've gone through the docs on server side NetConnection.call again and again, and seem to be doing it just the way they specify, but with no luck.

Thanks to anyone who can offer some help.

Cheers.

Evan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just thought I'd post my own answer here.  Regrettably, it was a simple lack of a application.acceptConnection in the onConnect that was causing my issue.

Didn't realize I had to explicitly call that, but it makes sense.

Hope it helps somebody out there trying to connect two FMS instances together...

:)